# Synonymize [exponent] and [exponents]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) refer to the exact same concept; there's no need for two tags, really. These two tags should probably be synonymized.

Comment: Shouldn't the title contain some info about the tags involved? It's in the hot meta box now.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: it's not so easy to find a title for a burnination request on Meta. It needs to be a rhyme, spell or other magic thing.

Comment: @AndrasDeak "*x to the power of y*" with y being the **exponent** is sometimes also referred to as "***rising** x to the yth power*", this is how the current title and tags in question are related. (I think)

Comment: @null that went way over my head, had to read your comment 3 times to figure out what you mean:) I see it now, although I have to say it's still a bit odd. But at least I see the concept, thanks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak one could try asking "Do the questions with these two tags have the same base?", because if the bases are equal, the exponents can be combined `x^y * x^z = x^(y+z)` and combining is somewhat synonymous to synonymising (or whatever that's called) which would be fitting, but this is not [math.se]. Although getting a burninate-request migrated to math.se because of it's title would be quite an achievement of meta title creativity.

Comment: @null I'd vote for that migration;)